# Speed up pairwise distance matrix calculation in Python

Tags: python, nested-loops, distance

I got about 9000 trajectoris, for a project I have to calculate the distance between each two of them. A trajectory consists of 11 points, and each points contains x and y coordinates. Simply generate sample dataset by:

```
import numpy as np
trajs = np.random.rand(9000,11,2)
```

I took the Frechet distance function from https://pypi.org/project/similaritymeasures/, which takes two trajectoris as input, and the output is a float value.

At the begining I wrote a nested for-loop:

```
from similaritymeasures import frechet_dist

distance_matrix = []

for i in trajs:
    for j in trajs:
        distance_matrix.append(frechet_dist(i,j))
```

It takes too long to get results.

Since the distance calculation is symmetrical (i.e. frechet_dist(t1,t2) = frechet_dist(t2,t1) ), I decrease the calculation times to half of above in this way:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

n = len(trajs)
distance_matrix = []
flag = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(flag,n):
        if i != j:
            distance_matrix.append(frechet_dist(trajs[i],trajs[j]))
    flag += 1
dist_mat = squareform(np.asarray(distance_matrix))
```

Now for 9000 trajectories, it takes 19 hours. I got the result but it still too long. Are there any methods to speed up the calculation?

Comment: Do you need to full distance matrix? Or perhaps only extreme values. Also, if you can use random data to generate a matrix of same shape, we can help you better.

Comment: The original idea was using distance matrix as similarity matrix to cluster those trajectories. Full matrix will be the input of some algorithms like DBSCAN. I update the sample dataset at question, thank you for the help!